# Dialect class not found. \when using hibernate

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate

This is my code. When i execute at a time it gives below error.
Initial SessionFactory creation failed.org.hibernate.HibernateException: Dialect class not found: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialectt

```
package com.bis.stock;
import org.hibernate.SessionFactory;
import org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration;
public class HibernateUtil {
    private static SessionFactory sessionFactory = buildSessionFactory();

    private static SessionFactory buildSessionFactory() {
        try {
            //Create the SessionFactory from hibernate.cfg.xml
            sessionFactory = new Configuration().configure("hibernate/Hibernate.cfg.xml").buildSessionFactory();
            return new Configuration()
                    .configure()
                    .buildSessionFactory();
        } catch (Throwable ex) {
            System.err.println("Initial SessionFactory creation failed." + ex);
            throw new ExceptionInInitializerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public static SessionFactory getSessionFactory() {
        return sessionFactory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Not sure if it's a typo on your part, but you have an extra `t` at the end of `MySQL5InnoDBDialectt`

Comment: Make sure that 
**<property name="dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect</property>** 
exists in your Hibernate.cfg.xml file. Also check for Typo mentioned by @peeskillet.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialect
```

instead of

```
org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5InnoDBDialectt
```